# How to calculate the percentage of overlap between 2 ranges with python

Tags: python, list, range, difference

I would like to calculate the percentage of overlap between 2 ranges.

for example: I have two lists x and y
x ['567.630', '592.927']
y ['593.000', '618.297']
In this case I would like an output of 0 as there is no overlap.

x ['793.843', '802.244']
y ['794.843', '803.244']
In this case I would like an output of 87%.

The total range of x and y are not always the same. It could be that x is 10s and y just 8s.

Could it be that there are some packages that perform these calculations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello and thank you for sharing your question with us. Would it be possible for you to add an example of input along with the corresponding output to your question?

Comment: A percentage is inherently a ratio. While it is reasonable to assume one part is the absolute overlap of the ranges, what is the second part? The smallest/largest/total/span/... range?

Comment: If you have a lot of intervals to check the overlap for, you can take advantage of pd.Interval.overlaps(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.overlaps.html) for such easy checks. It supports both open- and close- end intervals

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit shorter solution, where you can choose from which list you want to compare the overlap. If you want the overlap of e.g. [0,1] and [0,2] to be 100% you can just do max(x,y) from the output. I changed y list to show this.

```
x = [793.843, 802.244]

y = [794.843, 900.244] 


def overlap_percentage(xlist,ylist):
    min1 = min(xlist)
    max1 = max(xlist)
    min2 = min(ylist)
    max2 = max(ylist)

    overlap = max(0, min(max1, max2) - max(min1, min2))
    length = max1-min1 + max2-min2
    lengthx = max1-min1
    lengthy = max2-min2

    return 2*overlap/length , overlap/lengthx  , overlap/lengthy 

 average, x,y = overlap_percentage(x,y)
    
 print("average: ", average*100,"%    x: ", x*100,"%    y: ",y*100,"%")
```

output

```
average:  13.0 %    x:  88.0%    y:  7.0 %
```

Comment: you need to multiply by 100 to print the percentage properly

Comment: Thank you verry much! This indeed worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can accept my answer, if you think it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

No needs for extra imports. I assumed the data to be list of `float` numbers and not of string. The percentage is computed as overlapping over second interval, for the other case *un*comment the line in the implementation.

```
def overlapping_percentage(interval1: list, interval2: list) -> int:
    # min max of each intervals
    m1, M1 = min(interval1), max(interval1)
    m2, M2 = min(interval2), max(interval2)

    # find overlapping boundaries
    lb, ub = 0, 0 # lower and upper bound
    if m1 <= m2 <= M1:
        if M1 >= M2:    # i2 is contained in i1
            lb, ub = m2, M2
        elif M1 < M2:
            lb, ub = m2, M1

    elif m2 <= m1 <= M2:
        if M1 <= M2:    # i1 is contained in i2
            lb, ub = m1, M1
        elif M1 > M2:
            lb, ub = m1, M2

    # percentage
    percent = int((ub - lb) / (interval2[1] - interval2[0]) * 100)
    # percent = int((ub - lb) / (interval1[1] - interval1[0]) * 100) # for the other percentage uncomment this line
    print('overlapping interval', lb, ub)
    print(percent, '%')
    
    return percent


# intervals
#i1, i2 = [567.630, 592.927], [593.000, 618.297]
i1, i2 = [793.843, 802.244], [794.843, 803.244]

overlapping_percentage(i1, i2)
# overlapping interval 794.843 - 802.244
# 88 %
```

The overlapping part can be further compactified as follow

```
    ...
    # find overlapping boundaries
    lb, ub = 0, 0 # lower and upper bound
    if m1 <= m2 <= M1:
        lb, ub = m2, min(M1, M2)
    elif m2 <= m1 <= M2:
        lb, ub = m1, min(M1, M2)
    ...
```